# Using try catch to force communication between classes

Tags: java, try-catch

I am working on a personal finances application for android that tracks payments in categories (e.g. groceries, bills, going out etc.) Each category has a budget limit. I want to let the user be able to pass that limit and have other categories "help" with the money spent over this limit by lowering their budget limits. (I call this handling overflow)

What I do right now is, every time I make a change to a category instance that can lead to such an overflow, I return a boolean that specifies if there is overflow or not. Multiples categories are stored in a tracker class. When I make a change to a category, I check this return value to see if there is overflow and I handle it accordingly.

This feels pretty unsafe as I have to keep in my mind every time I should check for overflow. I was thinking I could use a try catch to do this and throw a custom made "OverflowException" from the category class, which would then be caught by the tracker class and handled accordingly. This way the code would force me to handle overflow whenever needed. Is it a good idea to use try catch like this?

Example of returning overflow check as I do it at the moment, Category class:

```
public boolean makePayment(Payment payment) {
        history.addTransaction(payment);
        // Spent changes, there might be overflow.
        spent += payment.getAbsValue();

        return hasOverflow();
    }
```

Example of handling overflow, CategoryTracker class:

```
public void makePayment(Category category, Payment payment, boolean assign) {
        if( (category == null) || (payment == null) ) { return; }
        if(history.hasTransaction(payment)) { return; }

        if(assign) {
            assignCategory(category, payment);
        }
        history.addTransaction(payment);
        // Spent changes, handle overflow if it's the case.
        if(category.makePayment(payment)) {
            adapter.handleOverflow(category);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about not returning a boolean but setting one static boolean variable in your main program. For example: `static boolean financialOverflow = false`, instead of throwing an exception, just flip that boolean to `true`. You may use exceptions like you've mentioned, but I find that a bit curios, because an exception is normally an abnormally, hence its name.

Comment: @paladin that's a very interesting way to go about it, but I am not sure how I can integrate it as I need to identify the category class that created the overflow, like I do here: `adapter.handleOverflow(category);` With a static boolean I pretty much have to guess which category instance created the overflow. Regarding using exceptions, that was what I was worrying about. But can't I consider an overflow to be an abnormality which has to be resolved?

Comment: Instead of just setting a boolean, you could also just set an unique id, aka `static long idOfProblematicCategory` for example. Or you could use an `enum` if applicable. But as I've mentioned, you also may use exceptions, they would work too. But in my opinion, I wouldn't do that, but that's just my opinion. Maybe someone other sees that in another way.